# ¿Cómo mostrar solo el nombre de la clase al ejecutar pruebas unitarias desde el proyecto gradle en IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, junit-5

Para IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition v2020.3.1

Cuando ejecuto una prueba desde un proyecto Gradle, se muestra el nombre completo de la clase.
Pero esto no sucede cuando ejecuto el mismo tipo de prueba en un proyecto Maven.
Es un poco molesto porque no es fácil de leer cuando ejecutas varias pruebas unitarias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En español por favor pues estás en so en español

Comment: CIerto, gracias por la observación.

Comment: Una captura de tu código no es útil para detectar el problema, por favor lee [sintaxis de markdown](https://markdown.es/sintaxis-markdown)

Comment: Mi problema no es de código, sino de configuración de IDE. Una imagen dice más que mil palabras.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la anotación [@DisplayName](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.3/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/DisplayName.html)

> @DisplayName is used to declare a custom display name for the annotated test class or test method.

Como indica el Javadoc, lo puedes aplicar tanto a la clase como a cada uno de los tests.

También hay desde la 5.4 un [@DisplayNameGeneration](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0-RC1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/DisplayNameGeneration.html), pero está marcado como "experimental" y en mi opinión es matar moscas a cañonazos, sobre todo si lo que quieres es renombrar la clase y no los tests.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo, con respecto a la anotación. Pero no es lo que busco.
Me gustaría saber si hay alguna configuración del IDE o sólo es para los proyectos gradle que se muestra así.